# Prove an integral expression equals $\pi\log 2/2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do you prove that:

> $$3\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}-2\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}-\int_0^{1/3} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}-\frac 12 \int_0^{3/4} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}=\frac{\pi\log 2}{2}$$

I have no clue on where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask the source of this problem?

Comment: *Any ideas?* - All these integrals can be expressed in terms of polylogarithms, and then various formulas involving the latter can be applied to them. Or you might try to use appropriate substitutions so that all their integration intervals become $(0,1)$, then use various formulas involving sums and differences of arctangents.

Comment: does it help you to use $\int \frac{\arctan x}{x} dx=c+x+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)^2}$?

Answer (score 4):

**Not an answer:** (couldn't fit it in comment box)

The function $\displaystyle \operatorname{Ti_2}(w) = \int_0^w \frac{\tan^{-1} t}{t}\,dt$ satisfies

$\displaystyle \operatorname{Ti_2}\left(\frac{w^2}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti_2}\left(\frac{w(w+2)}{2+2w}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti_2}\left(\frac{2w-2}{w(2-w)}\right)+\operatorname{Ti_2}\left(\frac{w}{w+2}\right) - \operatorname{Ti_2}\left(\frac{w}{2-w}\right)+\operatorname{Ti_2}\left(\frac{1}{1+w}\right) - \operatorname{Ti_2}\left(w-1\right) = 2\operatorname{Ti_2}\left(1\right)+\frac{\pi}{4}\log \frac{w(2-w)}{2+2w}$

for $w \in (0,2)$. Your case corresponds to $w = 1$.

Comment: Perfectly valid answer, in my opinion. At least if you quote a source for the formula.

Comment: @user111187 check identity (12) in [Inverse Tangent Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html). For a derivation of the formula you can check Lewin, L. Polylogarithms and Associated Functions. I have no slick solution atm.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Lewin! I'm impressed. I like the quote about the formula in this question "... and this in one form or another keeps cropping up."

Comment: @sciona can you write the proof given in Polylogarithms and Associated Functions in your answer?